# Jquery display message while php processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery ajax call to post process a form.
I want to display a loading message or image while the form is processed and when the action is completed to display a complete message.
How can I do it?
This is my jQuery code.

```
$s('body').on('click', '#group-update', function() {
    var formInputs = $s('input').serializeArray();
    var groupId = $s(this).data('group');
    var error = $s('#modal .info');
    var tr = $s('#dataT-attrgroup').find('tr.on_update');

    formInputs.push({
        name: 'id',
        value: groupId
    });

    $s.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php?controller=attribute&method=updateGroup',
        data: formInputs,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.response === false){
                error.addClass('info-error');
                error.html(data.message);
            }else{
                oTable.row(tr).data(data).draw();
                $s('#modal').modal('hide');
                tr.removeClass('on_update');
                $s.growl.notice({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Grupul de atribute a fost actualizat'
                });
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before ajax function display your loader and inside the success function from your ajax hide it.

As you can see in my example i inserted `$('.loader').show();` and `$('.loader').hide();`

```
$('.loader').show();
$s.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php?controller=attribute&method=updateGroup',
        data: formInputs,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.response === false){
                error.addClass('info-error');
                error.html(data.message);
            }else{
                oTable.row(tr).data(data).draw();
                $s('#modal').modal('hide');
                tr.removeClass('on_update');
                $s.growl.notice({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Grupul de atribute a fost actualizat'
                });
            }
            $('.loader').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: my for is validated before processed

Comment: the loading message should appear while the php call is made

Comment: i believe there are some advanced techniques for this, like file uploading through ajax but if you want to keep it simple then i`d suggest two options:
1. make the checking in js, 
2. create 2 ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP docs:

> The upload progress will be available in the $_SESSION superglobal when an upload is in progress, and when POSTing a variable of the same name as the session.upload_progress.name INI setting is set to. When PHP detects such POST requests, it will populate an array in the $_SESSION, where the index is a concatenated value of the session.upload_progress.prefix and session.upload_progress.name INI options. The key is typically retrieved by reading these INI settings, i.e.

You should take a look at : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-Session-Upload-Progress

I think this will definitely help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Display your message just before launching $.ajax();
And close it in the success (and error) callback functions.
example :

```
$s('body').on('click', '#group-update', function() {
var formInputs = $s('input').serializeArray();
var groupId = $s(this).data('group');
var error = $s('#modal .info');
var tr = $s('#dataT-attrgroup').find('tr.on_update');

formInputs.push({
    name: 'id',
    value: groupId
});

var dlg = $s('<div/>').text('your message').dialog();

$s.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'index.php?controller=attribute&method=updateGroup',
    data: formInputs,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    error:function() {
        dlg.dialog('close');
        },
    success: function(data) {

        dlg.dialog('close');

        if(data.response === false){
            error.addClass('info-error');
            error.html(data.message);
        }else{
            oTable.row(tr).data(data).draw();
            $s('#modal').modal('hide');
            tr.removeClass('on_update');
            $s.growl.notice({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Grupul de atribute a fost actualizat'
            });
        }

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go through ajax section of jquery documentation you will notice some more method like success ie error, beforesend, complete etc. Here is the code snippet.

```js
$s.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'index.php?controller=attribute&method=updateGroup',
  data: formInputs,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  beforeSend : function(){
    // load message or image
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // write code as per requirement
  },      
  complete : function(){
    // load complete message where you previously added the message or image, as a result previous one will be overwritten
  }  
});
```